# Random links placed in questions and answers

Tags: support, privileges, advertising

Is it normal that random links are being placed randomly throughout my questions and answers? Or is this just one of the advertising strategies used by Stack Overflow?

Comment: Too much random with you.

Comment: lol You have a very valid point!

Comment: For example? I, at least, have no idea what you are talking about. A screenshot would help.

Comment: Google 'links'.

Comment: Well I Googled [links](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=links&aq=f&oq=links&aqs=chrome.0.57j5j0l2j60l2.1879j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Did you mean the first hit: *Links of London online store for jewellery for men and women*? Or the second hit: *National Health Service LINks Healthwatch*? `</s>`

Comment: You mean "advertisements" not "links".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think that's not the case (thus my answer is wrong).

Comment: But he marked your answer as accepted didn't he? Anyway this question makes very little sense, hence the justified -10 (and going down)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The problem is, with my answer, the OP can assume that the links go away at 100 reputation and he cannot check if my answer is correct untill he or she gained those 100 reputation. But well it doesn't matter much though, both answers can be helpfull to others.

Comment: Correction, 200 reputation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. Almost certainly, you have some sort of browser extension, malware, etc., that is linkifying terms in your questions. The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768762/where-to-start-building-a-website-that-uses-a-database) of yours you commented on asking this ("Also, is it normal that random words throughout my question are linking themselves to random things.") does not contain any links at all. If you are seeing them, this is a problem with your computer, not with Stack Overflow.

There are advertisements on SO, but they never take the form of linkifying individual words in posts.

Comment: @SomeRandomProgrammer Does it occur on other sites as well?

Comment: Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is normal. This is (one of) the way(s) StackExchange can exist for free.

[When you gain 200 reputation, you'll see a lot less advertisement.](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads) Check out more privileges you can earn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

EDIT: After some consideration I think [this answer from Wooble is the correct one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181919/random-links-placed-in-questions-and-answers/181926#181926). Since the OP wasn't clear at all and didn't provide a screenshot, I assumed the OP ment advertisement, but it might be and possibly is malware like described in the other answer.

[See this question!!!](https://superuser.com/questions/488648/blocking-intellitxt-random-ad-links-on-browsers)

Comment: Read my edit, the other answer is actually the correct one, not mine!

Comment: +1 for realizing that Wooble's answer is actually correct

Comment: What @Doorknob said; and it was a good answer considering the information available when you posted!